# xarray.DataArray.diff vs. pandas.DataFrame.diff output is different

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I have been trying to migrate some of my higher dimensional data from pandas to xarray with the deprecation of pandas panels.  I would like to use the diff function in xarray but it's parameters and output are not the same as pandas.

The pandas version: "DataFrame.diff(self, periods=1, axis=0)" allows me to set the number of periods to shift for calculating difference. ie periods=2

The xarray version "DataArray.diff(self, dim: Hashable, n: int = 1, label: Hashable = 'upper')" only has the parameter n.  Which is the number of times the values are differenced.

Imports and example DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
​
data = np.random.randint(0, 9,(5,3))
date = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=5)
cols = ['A','B','C']
​
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=date, columns=cols)
​
print(df)
            A  B  C
2000-01-01  6  4  4
2000-01-02  1  1  5
2000-01-03  5  6  5
2000-01-04  5  8  4
2000-01-05  6  8  0
```

And corresponding DataArray:

```
da = xr.DataArray(df, dims = ['date', 'col'])
​
print(da)
<xarray.DataArray (date: 5, col: 3)>
array([[6, 4, 4],
       [1, 1, 5],
       [5, 6, 5],
       [5, 8, 4],
       [6, 8, 0]])
Coordinates:
  * date     (date) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-05
  * col      (col) object 'A' 'B' 'C'
```

DataFrame difference as expected and desired output with periods=1:

```
print(df.diff(periods=1))
​
              A    B    C
2000-01-01  NaN  NaN  NaN
2000-01-02 -5.0 -3.0  1.0
2000-01-03  4.0  5.0  0.0
2000-01-04  0.0  2.0 -1.0
2000-01-05  1.0  0.0 -4.0
```

Is the same as the DataArray output for n=1:

```
print(da.diff('date', n=1))
​
<xarray.DataArray (date: 4, col: 3)>
array([[-5, -3,  1],
       [ 4,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  2, -1],
       [ 1,  0, -4]])
Coordinates:
  * date     (date) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-02 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05
  * col      (col) object 'A' 'B' 'C'
```

But differs if the periods or n>1:

```
print(df.diff(periods=2))
​
              A    B    C
2000-01-01  NaN  NaN  NaN
2000-01-02  NaN  NaN  NaN
2000-01-03 -1.0  2.0  1.0
2000-01-04  4.0  7.0 -1.0
2000-01-05  1.0  2.0 -5.0
```

vs.

```
print(da.diff('date',n=2))
​
<xarray.DataArray (date: 3, col: 3)>
array([[ 9,  8, -1],
       [-4, -3, -1],
       [ 1, -2, -3]])
Coordinates:
  * date     (date) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05
  * col      (col) object 'A' 'B' 'C'
```

I can do a shift workaround to get the desired output and same answer as the DataFrame.diff:

```
print (da - da.shift(date=2))
​
<xarray.DataArray (date: 5, col: 3)>
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [-1.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  7., -1.],
       [ 1.,  2., -5.]])
Coordinates:
  * date     (date) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-05
  * col      (col) object 'A' 'B' 'C'
```

But I want to use the xarray.diff() instead if possible.  Any advice or explanation would be welcome please.

Answer (score 0):

`n` in `da.diff` is 'The number of times values are differenced'.

So if `n = 2`, it's second-order difference in xarray. while `df.diff` is always first order.